# Android Get Location

Tags: java, android, timer, gps, handler

I want to get the user location through GPS, if the GPS can't connect to the satellite within 30 seconds then I want to get the location through `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()`.

I can do both the work (i.e. get the location through GPS and from last known location), but I don't know how to do this using a timer (i.e. within 30 seconds). I heard that it can be done by using `Handler`s or Java `Timer` class. But I can't understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a boolean `gotLocation = true` when you get the location from GPS:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    if(location != null){
        gotLocation = true;
    }
}
```

And when you make your request like `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);`

add below a `Handler` with 30 seconds of delay like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!gotLocation){
                // get your last known location...
            }
        }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Simple, helpfull. Thank you Carnal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler's postdelay method to do the timer.
try

```
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }
    };

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("getLocation");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, listener, handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }, 30 * 1000);
```